# Use Contentful webhooks with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gatsby, contentful

We are struggling to find a way to use Contentful webbooks with Jenkins because we want to build a new page/content on contentful without manually deploying.

I didn't find useful/relevant information so far. Does anybody know if it's possible?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you combine the [generic webhook plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin) with a custom [Contentful Webhook](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/webhooks/#create-and-configure-a-webhook).

1. You first need to configure the generic webhook plugin in jenkins to trigger
   the job you want.
2. Then you create a Contentful webhook pointing to your jenkins url

   ```
   http://<YOUR JENKINS URL>/jenkins/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke
   ```
3. If you have multiple jobs in jenkins and you only want to trigger a specific one you can use [tokens in your jenkins plugin config](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin#trigger-only-specific-job).

   ```
   http://<YOUR JENKINS URL>/jenkins/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=abc123
   ```